# Laravel pivot table null foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Say that I have 3 tables:

**table1**

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | some  |
|  2 | some2 |
+----+-------+
```

**table2**:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | some  |
|  2 | some2 |
+----+-------+
```

**table1_table2**:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| table1_id | table2_id |      settings       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|         1 | 1         | {'something':false} |
|         2 | null      | {'something':false} | <--- :(
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Then I would have the following models

```
class Table1 extends Model {
    [...]
    public function table2()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Table2', 'table1_table2', 'table1_id', 'table2_id')
            ->withPivot('settings');
    }
}

class Table2 extends Model {
    [...]
    public function table1()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Table1', 'table1_table2', 'table2_id', 'table1_id')
            ->withPivot('settings');
    }
}
```

Everything is okay when I insert in the pivot table both id's.

Problem occurs(on data retrieval) because I have cases where I insert **null** values in **table2_id**.

```
Table1::find(1)->table2(); //Gives back the first entry OK (as array)
Table1::find(2)->table2(); //Gives back empty array
```

**My question is:** Is there a way to mark **table2_id** as optional (so that Laravel makes a left join rather than a normal join)?

Comment: Well... yes, don't make it a pivot? :) You can use two belongsTo relationships instead, and make the second one optional. I imagine that would make the logic cleaner.

Comment: I ended up with your solution because it was the only way unfortunately. It's hard when you have to transition from one framework to another :D

Comment: Glad it worked. :)

Comment: You could put it as an answer: make the pivot table into a model then manage the missing null-able entity through this model etc (something like that). Thanks

Comment: Sure, thanks for allowing me. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just skip the pivot entirely, and make it a regular table + model which belongsTo both tables, but the latter one optionally.